# /me/events - Events API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I've read conflicting information about this bit. But we've received complaints that users are unable to import their events in our application, although we have an approved App that has the "user_events" permission.

In short, the response when querying `me/events` using a user access token of the mentioned app is empty:

```
Edge: me/events
{
  "data": []
}
```

Now, the funny part is, if you are a **developer** of the application in question, the endpoint will happily send you your own events over the API.

Is this intended behavior according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/?

> This edge is only available to a limited number of approved apps. Unapproved apps querying this edge will receive an empty data set in response. You cannot request access to this edge at this time.

Was there any communication about this? We have updated our application after they restricted the public access in May to use the `user_events` permission, but it looks like this access is now disabled as well, and even in a very sneaky way that makes it very hard to detect? Also, I did not read anything about this in any breaking change logs?

I'm just searching for clarification, because there is no way to properly contact Facebook regarding this issue.